# Make possible to open p:button in new window by Ctrl+click or Middleclick like links

Tags: jsf, button, primefaces, new-window

I have a primefaces (5.1) datatable with some buttons in the rightermost column:

```
            <p:column headerText="Actions" style="width: 60px">
                <p:button id="uploadButton" title="upload files"
                    icon="fa fa-edit" outcome="uploadFilesToVersion">
                    <f:param name="versionId" value="#{version.id}" />
                </p:button>

            <!-- other buttons come here-->

            </p:column>
```

note that "version" is the local (loop) variable of the sourrounding p:dataTable and uploadFilesToVersion.xhtml is a view for the user to upload files to a "version" with id = version.id)

Note that the button doeas not invoke any bean method, I just used the p:button element becaus of its style. Now I want to give the user the possibility to open the outcome of the button (i.e. an URL) in a new brower tab/window. This would be beneficial because I want the dataTable's filter state to be preserved in the meanwhile (its lost when the user clicks "back" in the browser).

How can that be achieved?

EDIT: Of course one could use some CSS to mimick the appearance of a button, but I wanted to avoid that:

```
            <p:column headerText="Actions" style="width: 60px">

              <p:link id="uploadButton" title="upload files"
                outcome="uploadFilesToVersion"
                styleClass="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only">
                 <span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c fa fa-edit"></span>              
                 <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">ui-button</span>
                 <f:param name="versionId" value="#{version.id}" />
            </p:link>

        <!-- other buttons come here-->

        </p:column>
```

Comment: 'wanted' is past tense. So you changed your mind?

Comment: yes, based on BalusC's answer I "changed my mind", so to say

Comment: so the edit is kind of an additional answer? Then post it as such, or 'edit' the answer by BalusC and add it there so the passing of the param is also in there (and also please post PF version info)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's **not possible** as the `<p:button>` navigates using JavaScript and not using `<a href>`. The behavior you're looking for is only possible using `<a href>`.

Your best bet is to use a `<h|p:link>`, which generates an `<a>`,  and style it to look like a button.

```
<h:link ... styleClass="ui-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
    <i class="fa fa-edit" />
</h:link>
```

Wrap if necessary in a [tagfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen) to reduce boilerplate.

```
<my:linkButton ... icon="fa fa-edit" />
```